# iOS: Autolayout flexible margins

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a `UILabel` object in my `UIView`. I want to let this lable moving respectively when its super view size changes. This is like the old `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`, `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`, `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin`, so that if the superview height changed, the label top margin would change respectively, and the same for left margin.

How to do this with `Autolayout` not the old `autoresizingmask`?

Comment: If the top margin should change is the bottom margin fixed? In this case you only have to add a constraint which defines the bottom margin.

Comment: I want all the four margins move respectively like the old behavior

Comment: @dasdom I set a bottom constraint to stick a subview to the bottom of a view controller's view, but the subview jumps up & down during rotation. But, with `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`, the subview stays pinned to the bottom of its superview during rotation. I guess I'll just stick with `autoresizingMask`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the multiplier property of the NSLayoutConstraint to achieve this. You can't mix edge attributes with size attributes, but you *can* use the bottom and right edges as proxies for size.

```
UIView * parent = [[UIView alloc] init];

UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];

[parent addSubview:label];
[label setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

//Label top stays at 20% of the height of the view
NSLayoutConstraint * topMargin = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:label
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:parent
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                             multiplier:0.2f
                                                               constant:0.0f];
[parent addConstraint:topMargin];
```

Comment: Can I use IB to form these constraints?